# Why host command works for reverse DNS testing but not otherwise?

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I can test my zone files with `named-checkzone`, and it looks ok.

`45.20.10.in-addr.arpa.zone` zone file (reverse DNS):

```
$TTL 30
@ IN SOA localhost. admin.example.com (
2017080101  ;serial
3H      ;refresh
1H      ;retry
2H      ;expire
1M)     ;neg ttl
@ IN NS localhost.;
;generate 1-254
$GENERATE 1-254 $ IN PTR host$.example.com
```

`example.com.zone` zone file:

```
$TTL 30
@ IN SOA localhost. admin.example.com. (
2017072702  ; serial
3       ; refresh
1       ; retry
2       ; expire
1M)     ; negative TTL
            IN NS localhost.;
www.example.com.    IN A 192.168.111.45
www.example.com.    IN AAAA fe80::22c9:d0ff:1ecd:c0ef
foo.example.com.    IN A 192.168.121.11
bar.example.com.    IN CNAME www.example.com.
;generate 100 hosts
$GENERATE 1-100 host$.example.com. IN A 10.20.45.$
```

I can test the zone file with the dig command like so `dig @localhost -t A www.example.com`.

I can also test the reverse zone file like so `host 10.20.45.55 localhost`.

In the man page of the host command it is said that one could also test like so `host host55.example.com localhost`, but this yields an error message:

```
Using domain server:
Name: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases: 

Host host55.example.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

I am clueless about why that does not work. Any help and explanation would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation about `$GENERATE`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/generate.html) gives the following syntax:

```
$GENERATE start-stop[/step] lhs[{offset[,width[,type]]}] rr-type rhs[{offset[,width[,type]]}]
```

where `rr-type` is CNAME, DNAME, A, AAAA, NS, PTR, ...

Therefore, your line:

```
$GENERATE 1-100 host$.example.com. IN A 10.20.45.$
```

should instead be:

```
$GENERATE 1-100 host$.example.com. A 10.20.45.$
```

It's strange that `bind` didn't spit any error/warning message about this.